# Julia: implement standard math operations for types

Tags: julia

Is there a way to implement basic arithmetic for user created types in julia

For example:

```
type Foo
    bar::Float32
    foo::Int32
end
a = Foo(3.23,23)
b = Foo(4.56,54)
c = a+b
```

How, if at all possible can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Note if you have a lot of these operations you want to extend to your new type, you can save yourself an awful lot of typing by using [metaprogramming for code generation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Code-Generation-1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to explicitly import the Base functions for adding methods for your own types on them. I'm not sure if this the best way to do it, but the following would enable you to add two Foos together.

```
type Foo
bar::Float32
foo::Int32
end

import Base: +
+(a::T, b::T) where {T<:Foo} = Foo(a.bar+b.bar, a.foo+b.foo)

a = Foo(3.23,23)
b = Foo(4.56,54)
c = a+b
```